# Wiegand 26b (Indala Lite) as NFC on Android

Tags: android, protocols, nfc, rfid, wiegand

I am looking for a way to load the card we are using at work into the phone so I can use NFC on the phone to touch the wall reader and get it work.

I have found a lot on the internet, however when I download any of the RFID or NFC reader apps to load the tag, it is not reading anything at all.

The card we using is:
https://www.adiglobal.cz/cz/produkty130:1871927/bezkontaktni-karta-indala-lite

If there is a way, just some link, where I can grab some info how to, would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The card you are refering to is an [HID Indala](https://www.hidglobal.com/products/readers/indala) card. It uses a different operating frequency than NFC. The card operates on 125 kHz while NFC operates on 13.56 MHz. Consequently, it cannot be read with NFC devices.